# flask error with .env file then sending mail

Tags: python, flask, smtp

i have problem i got error like thism then i try send mail in flask project.

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I think its problem with .env file reading because then i write not like this

```
  s = smtplib.SMTP('MAIL_SERVER')
```

But use ip like this

```
   s = smtplib.SMTP('8.8.8.8')
```

Its working well.
i try do something like this  but nothing working

```
app.config['mail_server'] 
env['mail_server']
```

So any one can help me with this problem? if u need more info ask it in comment. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is that the whole traceback?

Comment: no, i will update full traceback

Comment: If you have .env with MAIL_SERVER, shouldn't you use `os.getenv('MAIL_SERVER')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(os.getenv('MAIL_SERVER'))
```